# Reset 100 passwords in Sandbox environment

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using  the SetPass code to reset passwords in the QA Sandbox password for 100 test users that we are using for performance testing and it reset the password, but upon log-in it is requiring the passwords to be manually reset.

I turned the "Password Never Expires" on the profiles used in the testusers but it still required the passwords to be reset upon login.

This is the anonymous process I ran and it *worked*, in that it changed the password on all 100 users, but then it still required a password change upon first log in - I need it NOT to force a password change on first login:

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>(); 
userList = [SELECT Id from User WHERE username like 'Test.User%' and isActive = TRUE]; 
for (User u : userList) 
{ 
System.setPassword(u.Id, '***********'); 
}
```

Comment: While creating community users, I have faced this very same predicament. Upon first login, the users are forced to change their passwords.

Comment: Here is one trick that *may* work for you.
```System.resetPassword('UserID,false);
System.setPassword('UserID'welcome');```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use System.resetPassword() method.

```
System.ResetPasswordResult rstPSWRDrs = system.resetPassword(userTempObj.Id, true);
```

**Syntax :**

> resetPassword(userId, sendUserEmail)

**userId**

Id of user, whom password we are resetting.

**sendUserEmail**

*true* - Send a mail to user, containing reset link

*false*- Don't send mail to user

> **Update**
>
> PS: This method will give you error if your user profile has SSO enabled.

[For more details, click here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm)